# Buttons Link to Nested Page

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm new to using R's Shiny package and have a question regarding action buttons and using them to link to other pages. I'm trying to create a tab on the app that will have multiple 'buttons' that each link to their own subpages, without using something like **tabset** that would have all these subpages be simultaneously visible.

I created a mockup of what i'd like to look like:

[image: Tab1 Page, with all the subpage Buttons: Button1, Button2, Button3]

[image: Button1 subpage, which would be linked to/accessed through the buttons on Tab1 page]

In writing, this is the general structure I'd like to create:

```
Navbar: HOME; TAB1; TAB2; TAB3

   Within TAB2: Button1; Button2; Button3

         By clicking on Button1: Button1 Subpage
```

The closest thing I've been able to find to easily implement this would be using a tabset. However, I don't like the way it looks and would rather implement it using buttons.

I have some web design experience using jquery/html/css and could code the action in a separate .js file and load it into the R file, however, I want to code it in Shiny for future users to more easily understand and edit the code.

Do you have any advice as to how I could go about this? Is **tabset** the only way to do it cleanly within the Shiny framework?

I apologize in advance if my question isn't well formulated, I'm very new to using Shiny.

Comment: One way to do this is to use a hidden tabsetpanel and change the tabs using updateTabsetpanel and observeEvent() in the server. The idea is nicely described here: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html?q=hidden#dynamic-visibility

Comment: See [brochure](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/multi-page-shiny-applications-with-brochure/) and [shiny.router](https://appsilon.com/shiny-router-020/).

Comment: Thank you for your responses! @StéphaneLaurent, do you know if shiny.router works with Shiny's navbarpage? I'm having issues integrating it with my existing code that is based in Shiny's navbarpage structure, and all the documentation on shiny.router I can find suggests setting up the navbar through css rather than through navbarPage or other Shiny methods. I'm considering using shinyjs's onclick, though I've had issues with implementing that as well. Can onclick work with the router package? I've only gotten it to work getting to external links (outside the app). Thank you so much!